# Compile Error: Ambiguous name detected for mail function

Tags: c++, vba, excel

Respected Expert, Please find my below code where I am facing the **Compile Error: Ambiguous name detected** error in **RangetoHTML = Replace function**.Please help me out on the same.

```
     Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

                Dim fso As Object
                Dim ts As Object
                Dim TempFile As String
                Dim TempWB As Workbook


                TempFile = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
                Set x = ActiveWorkbook
                Set TempWB = x

                Set rng = Nothing
                Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

                With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
                     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
                     Filename:=TempFile, _
                     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(2).Name, _
                     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(2).UsedRange.Address, _
                     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
                    .Publish (True)
                End With


                Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
                RangetoHTML = ts.readall
                ts.Close
     M=   RangetoHTML    
RangetoHTML = Replace(M, "align=center x:publishsource=", "align=left x:publishsource=")

     ''In Above code RangetoHTML for Replace I am facing the error.


    Set ts = Nothing
                Set fso = Nothing
                Set TempWB = Nothing
            End Function
```

Comment: how is this related to `C++` ? What is the point of the function to get `rng` as a parameter,if the first thing you do is `Set rng = Nothing` ?

Comment: Create a local string variable to use in place of RangeToHTML. Assign that variable to RangeToHTML just before you leave the function.

Comment: @RichHolton I have u **M** variable to in the place of **RangetoHTML** same i have updated in my code above. Now I am facing **wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment** error.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested by Rick...you can try this

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

            Dim fso As Object
            Dim ts As Object
            Dim TempFile As String
            Dim TempWB As Workbook


            TempFile = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
            Set x = ActiveWorkbook
            Set TempWB = x

            Set rng = Nothing
            Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

            With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
                 SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
                 Filename:=TempFile, _
                 Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(2).Name, _
                 Source:=TempWB.Sheets(2).UsedRange.Address, _
                 HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
                .Publish (True)
            End With

        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
                    M = ts.readall
                    ts.Close
                    M = Replace(M, "align=center x:publishsource=", "align=left x:publishsource=")
        ''In Above code RangetoHTML for Replace I am facing the error.
                    RangetoHTML = M

        Set ts = Nothing
        Set fso = Nothing
        Set TempWB = Nothing
        End Function
```

Comment: I am still facing the same error, could you help me how can I set the alignment (i.e.=left) in any other way.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? What value does M have just before the call to Replace? Maybe you should Dim M as String?